# Download zip file without using webclient c#

Tags: c#, web-scraping

Want to download zip file without using web client because getting error 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.' after passing proper headers to request.

Need alternative for webclient and httpwebrequest.

Thanks in advance !

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse WebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(URL);

                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    // Above three lines can be replaced with new helper method below
                    // string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

                    Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
                }
            }
```

Comment: As you're receiving a 403 response whichever method you use, it would suggest that you either aren't passing the right credentials, or you're not passing them correctly. It would help if you could post your code (excluding any sensitive information, of course) to help ascertain which of those it is and identify the problem if it's the latter of the two.

Comment: You should show us  _"passing proper headers to request"_. WebClient and WebRequest are old but not broken. The error is yours.

Comment: Posted code.please check and let me know

Comment: You are not setting any Headers at all. See WebCLient.Credentials and look up how to use them.

Comment: Google: "you are using httpclient wrong".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpClient` which has been introduced with the ASP.NET Web API release and is also included in .NET Core.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2

It looks like your server requires Authentication to download the ZIP-File -which you can do using `HttpClient` depending on which type of Authentication your server requires.

Comment: Still getting same response 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'

Comment: As said, your server requires Authentication and Authorization (`403` says you might be authenticated but you don't have permissions = Unauthorized)

Comment: Thanks, I will check

Comment: Done that too. set Authorization header with proper token. Issue not resolved